# Kubernetes Ingress SSL Certificate issue

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have created a Kube certificate using certificate and key. When I try to access my services it returns an error saying "Server can't provide a secure connection". When accessing through curl it shows the following error.
I have tried everything that shows in the internet and also when I describe my ingress it shows that the secret has added.

```
* About to connect() to ***.***.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying IP...
* Connected to ***.***.com (IP) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

Comment: are you using something like cert manager?

Comment: No not using a cert manager.

Comment: so have you specifically set the tls section on the ingress? maybe you could share your ingress?

Comment: yes. I have specifically set the tls section.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with the wildcard dns name. the below one doesnt appear to be correct.

`***.***.com`

regenerate the certificate for dns name like `*.<application-domain>.com`

Comment: No No I censored the information there wildcard appears correctly.